# NodeMCU returns ERROR for commands sent from ESPlorer

Tags: nodemcu, esplorer

I have a NodeMCU dev kit v2 (Lolin) and I am trying to program it with NodeMCU script. I am using ESPlorer and so far I have managed to talk to it using AT commands (of course from ESPlorer tool). I managed to connect to Wi-Fi network using AT commands as well.

But when I try to Send NodeMCU commands (e.g. `node.heap()`), it shows 'ERROR' in the terminal window of ESPlorer tool.

Version information can be retrieved using AT commands and it is attached herewith.
[Screenshot of version info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7bIH.jpg)

I have also attached the response I get when I run NodeMCU commands. You see the IP addresses since I have already connected to Wi-fi network using AT commands.
[Screenshot of Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkPdT.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't know for sure but it looks like your device doesn't have the NodeMCU firmware loaded. From http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/:

- build the firmware
- flash it to the device
- upload Lua/NodeMCU code

Comment: I thought the dev kit comes pre-installed with firmware. :( I think it might be the reason then. I'll try to flash the device and try again. I'll post here with the outcome.

Thanks for your guidance :)

Comment: There are lots of devkit clones and they all come with different stuff pre-loaded. Even if you get the original Amica NodeMCU devkit (see [comparison](http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/)) it ships with a totally outdated NodeMCU firmware.

Comment: Can I use the latest firmware to flash it?

Comment: Depends on what you consider "latest" (it's 1.5.4.1). Just follow the guidelines in our docs and ask specific i.e. new questions here if you're stuck.

Comment: Can this be closed?

Comment: I used nodemcu-build.com and downloaded the bin file. I successfully flashed it and I could see the green icon in nodemcu flasher.

After that I removed the module from the computer and plugged it back. Then the blue led in ESP8266 board started flashing rapidly and I cannot connect to it in ESPlorer. :(

Comment: I think I got it fixed by accident. After unsuccessful attempts to flash nodemcu, I pressed 'Restore default' button in Advanced tab of nodemcu flasher.

It replaced the path in Config tab to 'INTERNAL://NODEMCU'. Then I flashed once again without knowing the meaning of above path. Anyway, it served my purpose and I can see that nodecmu is installed. Can you please explain what has happened here? :)

But I have no idea what modules have been installed there. I need MQTT. Please let me know how can I know what modules have been installed?

Comment: NodeMCU Flasher starts to become a problem of its own. It appears to be unmaintained and the NodeMCU firmware it includes (what you just flashed) is from March 2015 (https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-flasher/tree/master/Resources/Binaries). Totally outdated and unreliable.

Comment: Could you please let me know what tool should I use instead of the one I am using then? I sincerely expect your help.

Comment: I couldn't get it fixed yet. If I flash the latest firmware, module gets stuck. I even followed the Upgrade guidelines. Do you think if I switch to python utility to flash the module, would it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, unless the device itself is broken. esptool.py is our recommended flash tool for two reasons: all the NodeMCU committers us it (i.e. we're familiar with it), NodeMCU Flasher is Windows-only and seems to have been abandoned. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39144442/131929.

Comment: Finally managed to get it working by following instructions given in [stackoverflow.com/a/39144442/131929](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39144442/131929) as suggested by Marcel. This can be closed now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great, then please upvote and/or accept this answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/257994 for details.