# ESP8266 cannot read flash after programming

Tags: esp8266, flash-memory

I have written the flash on an ESP-12E, using a custom build with the base modules + OneWire and mDNS.
The build is from a website i've used before and the build have always worked.

The flash write was apparently successful, yet after the write the ESP started to send garbage data and it hasn't stopped yet.

The ESP8266 download tool from Espressif fails to program the flash, and so does esptool.
The fun part is: I can actually read the MAC for both the AP and the STATION.

GPIO0/2 changes have no effect whatsoever, garbage data still comes in.
Tried to read the data with ESPlorer, PuTTY (Serial) and Teraterm and the problem is the same.

Also tried all standard Baudrates from 9600 to 230400...

And now i'm completely out of ideas.
Here's an image about the error on the Espressif downloader:
[image: After getting sync i get this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to familiarize yourself with the [upgrading section in the NodeMCU docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/#upgrading-firmware). More specifically you need to flash the `esp_init_data_default.bin` of the Espressif SDK your firmware builds upon to the correct memory address.

I don't know how to do that with the NodeMCU Flasher (project seems to have stalled btw) but with esptool.py the command is as follows:

```
esptool.py --port <serial-port-of-ESP8266> write_flash -fm dio -fs 32m 0x00000 <nodemcu-firmware>.bin 0x3fc000 esp_init_data_default.bin
```

Comment: Thanks. It appears you are my saviour once more.